# Slow printing in company network, no network problems, what else could it be?

Tags: networking, printer, network-printer

In one company everyone is allowed to use the network with their own devices. The companys laptops are all in a domain, passwords are stored on a server.

There are printers too, everyone can add them by searching in "devices and printers", everyone can print.

I normally use only one printer in this company, I havent tried others. This printer can be found twice in "devices and printers" search, first with its IP address, second with :54000 as port behind the IP address.

I am connecting via LAN cable, the printer is connected via cable too, ping to the printer is good and below 1ms.

The problem is, the printing is slow. I send a print job, it takes very long to start printing, then one page is printed then there is a pause. Then the next page is being printed, then a pause again, till the document is finished.

I heard employees from this company with their own laptops and domain have this problem too, I think it is getting better, when I add the :54000 printer instead of the IP address only printer, but this is only a guess.

It is not a LAN problem, what could it be then? Printing from USB stick is fast, it is a big office Canon color laserprinter.

My laptop has Windows 8.1 x64, 16gb RAM, SSD. Printing at home is no problem.

Comment: What are you printing?  text,images, or etc.  If you have document filled with 600dpi images it is going to slow it down.  Some documents, the text is actually an embedded image.  How big are the files?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very experienced in Windows Servers but I am sure that the company might have a print server that processes every print jobs in your domain. When you request a print job in the domain, it could be sent to the print server and in this case, the print server might be slow to respond in which causes the problem.

However, you have said that it became a bit faster when you add the port number after the IP address of the printer. This could be because that you directly request a print job from the printer but not from the print server.

You may have to talk to the network administrators from your company about the print server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The following are just tips and tricks from my personal experience and web searches performed in the past. 
The Biggest success is to turn off WSD on the Printer or copier. 
It will prevent the OS from discovering the printer and attaching a generic driver to it.
If that is not the issue try one or all of these items to see if they help you to resolve the issue.

•   Remove and reinstall the printer.

•   IP conflicts and port settings. Deleting the port and recreating it can help.

•   Spool print documents so program finishes printing faster

•   Start printing after last page is spooled

•   Print Spooled Documents First

•   Move the spool folder to a different drive on the server. By default it is on the C drive.

•   Printer driver version not current.

•   Turn off unnecessary items such as Apple Talk, Pop, FTP, etc.. and make certain time settings are correct under SNTP or date and time settings of printer.

•   Close open connections. Use server management function to see open connections and close them.

•   Check for collisions. Often a power reset of your network switch will resolve this without having to do much troubleshooting. Adding a network switch in line with the printer will be another good test for this.

•   A network bridge will resolve these issues as well.

•   A packet capture could help diagnose collisions and packets that are taking time to resolve communication requests.